# Does WebClient.DownloadFileAsync overwrite the file if it already exists on disk?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I can't find any information on my question. Please excuse me if my search efforts have not been good enough to find the answer. I just want to avoid spinning my wheels.

Thanks!

Follow up: If it doesn't overwrite, how can I get it to (if possible)?

Comment: Seems like it would be simple enough to just try it and find out.  If it doesn't; check for a file with that name before downloading and delete it before downloading.

Comment: This seems like a good question for Google, if you ask me (which you did!) ;]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A 30 second test confirms that it does overwrite

Test:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe"), @"C:\Test.exe");
}
```

Test.exe is overwitten if downlaoded again

Comment: Thanks, I just saved 28 seconds. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `WebClient` class is obviously designed to suppress a lot of detail and control. You can write your own method to asynchronously download a file very easily and control how the downloaded data is written to disc.

I know for sure that [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265751/Application-Auto-update-via-Online-Files-in-Csharp) at codeproject contains a class which downloads a file using `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` which allows for much more control. See the class contained named `webdata`. The code you can need to pay attention too:

```
FileStream newFile = new FileStream(targetFolder + file, FileMode.Create);
newFile.Write(downloadedData, 0, downloadedData.Length);
newFile.Close();
```

The [`FileMode Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) contains a series of members that dictate the behaviour of saving a file `FileMode.CreateNew` will throw an `IOException` if a file already exists. As where `FileMode.Create` will overwrite files if possible.

If you insist on using `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` then, as the other fellas have already mentioned: you can just inform the user that an existing file will be overwritten by means of an `OpenFileDialog` but some downloads can be time consuming and there's nothing to say that the user has not created another file during the download.

Answer (score 1):

If the file exists, yes.

If you are renaming it, or if you have it hooked into an `OpenFileDialogue()`, that's your discretion.